# Pivot columns in Data Frame

Tags: r

I have the data frame below:

```
data<-data.frame(names= c("Bob","Bob", "Fred","Fred","Tom"), id =c(1,1,2,2,3),amount = c(100,200,400,500,700), status = c("Active","Not Active","Active","Retired","Active"))
data

 names id amount     status
1   Bob  1    100     Active
2   Bob  1    200 Not Active
3  Fred  2    400     Active
4  Fred  2    500    Retired
5   Tom  3    700     Active
```

I would like to Pivot the "Status" column so the "amount" data appears under the new status columns so that the result looks like this:

```
names     id    Active    Not Active  Retired
Bob       1      100         200
Fred      2      400                   500
Tom       3      700
```

Is this possible? What is the best way?

Comment: In anything real (read: not Excel) this is _"reshape data from long to wide format_": `library(tidyr) ; spread(data, status, amount)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dcast` from the package `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(data, names + id ~ status, value.var="amount")

#   names id Active Not Active Retired
# 1   Bob  1    100        200      NA
# 2  Fred  2    400         NA     500
# 3   Tom  3    700         NA      NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I am now compelled to turn a comment into an answer. Here's the Hadleyverse version:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(data, status, amount)

##   names id Active Not Active Retired
## 1   Bob  1    100        200      NA
## 2  Fred  2    400         NA     500
## 3   Tom  3    700         NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the base method:

```
> xtabs(amount~names+status, data=data)
      status
names  Active Not Active Retired
  Bob     100        200       0
  Fred    400          0     500
  Tom     700          0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `base R` option

```
 reshape(data, idvar=c('names', 'id'), timevar='status', direction='wide')
 #  names id amount.Active amount.Not Active amount.Retired
 #1   Bob  1           100               200             NA
 #3  Fred  2           400                NA            500
 #5   Tom  3           700                NA             NA
```